In Excel, I want to order my values by price when I am summing and grouping by using UNIQUE and SUMIF
I am trying to create a cheeky excel spreadsheet to track how much my family spends on groceries.  I have it mostly working using UNIQUE and SUMIF, as shown below. I am basically just adding new values to the bottom of Column A, it's cost in Column B, and then Column E looks for unique values in A and puts them in E, and F SUMs the cost for each item.
My question is, is there a way to order column E and F so that the items we spend the most on are on top?



Try wrapping within SORT() function, try using the following formula:


=LET(
     α, A2:B15,
     δ, TAKE(α,,1),
     φ, UNIQUE(δ),
     SORT(HSTACK(φ, SUMIFS(TAKE(α,,-1), δ,φ)),2,-1))


The above solution is probably applicable to your version of Excel, it is only one single dynamic array formula, therefore you dont need to change the range every single time, preferably using Structured References aka Tables is most suggested.
However, if you had access to GROUPBY() then:
=GROUPBY(A2:A15,B2:B15,SUM,,0,-2)


Now, refer this one below uses Tables whenever you add any new Items the formula will automatically pick up and give you the instant output, now thats the benefit of using Structured References aka Tables:


=GROUPBY(Groceries[Item],Groceries[Cost],SUM,,0,-2)


Or,
=LET(
     α, Groceries,
     δ, TAKE(α,,1),
     φ, UNIQUE(δ),
     SORT(HSTACK(φ, SUMIFS(TAKE(α,,-1), δ,φ)),2,-1))


Where Groceries refers to the table name, you may need to change as per your preferences or choice.

BTW, you can avoid those multiple steps and can use the following ,however, it will be not that efficient like the other ones:
=LET(
     α, Groceries,
     δ, TAKE(α,,1),
     SORT(UNIQUE(HSTACK(δ, SUMIFS(TAKE(α,,-1), δ,δ))),2,-1))



Holy smokes, this is amazing. I look forward to trying these!!!  Gimme a day or two--currently packing :)

@Jeff.Clark No issues at all, please take your own sweet time

With SORTBY
=LAMBDA(item, cost,
    LET(
        items, UNIQUE(FILTER(item, NOT(ISBLANK(item)))),
        item_cost, SUMIFS(cost, item, items),
        SORTBY(HSTACK(items, item_cost), item_cost, -1)
    )
)(A2:A500, B2:B500)


